# Calculating infinite series for a hospital waiting queue

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, queueing-theory

For my project, I had to simulate a hospital waiting queue, and ended up stuck with this equation.

$$ 
1=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu+i\gamma}\right)^iP_0
$$

Could any kind soul help me with the RHS of the equation?

Also, I have found out that this expression $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^i$ can be simplified to get $\frac{1}{1-\frac{\lambda}{\mu}}$ but I don't understand why. Please enlighten me on this. Thank you!

---

Edit:

Thanks Almagest and Did for helping and clarifying. I realised that the equation is wrong; what I was trying to come up with was this:

$$
P_1 = \frac{\lambda P_0}{\mu} 
$$
$$
P_2 =  \frac{\lambda P_1}{\mu + \gamma} = \frac{\lambda^2 P_0}{\mu(\mu + \gamma)} 
$$
$$
P_3 =  \frac{\lambda P_2}{\mu + 2\gamma} = \frac{\lambda^3 P_0}{\mu(\mu + \gamma)(\mu + 2\gamma)} 
$$
$$
P_4 =  \frac{\lambda P_3}{\mu + 3\gamma} = \frac{\lambda^4 P_0}{\mu(\mu + \gamma)(\mu + 2\gamma)(\mu + 3\gamma)} 
$$
and so on..

Where:

- $P_n$ is the probability that there are n patients in the system.
- $\lambda$ is the arrival rate.
- $\mu$ is the service rate.
- $\gamma$ is the death rate of the patient.

Therefore, I want to sum up all the terms from 0 to infinity to be 1, and express $\gamma$ in terms of $\lambda, \mu,$ and $P_0$.

Comment: I don't know any general expression for your sum, but it would be easy to evaluate numerically if you had values for $\lambda,\mu,\gamma$. On your second question, let the sum be $s$. Multiply by $\frac{\lambda}{\mu}$ you get the same sum less the first term, ie $s\frac{\lambda}{\mu}=s-1$, so $s=\frac{1}{1-\frac{\lambda}{\mu}}$.

Comment: Sure about the $i$ in $\mu+i\gamma$?

Comment: @Did I was incorrect, thanks for clarifying! I have edited my post, could you see if it is possible to simplify the equation and express $\gamma$ in terms of $\lambda, \mu$ and $P_0$?

Comment: Well, using $u=\lambda/\gamma$ and $v=\mu/\gamma$, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n=P_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{u^n}{v(v+1)\cdots(v+n-1)}=P_0M(1,v;u),$$ where $M$ is [Kummer's function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function), hence $$P_0=\frac1{M(1,\mu/\gamma;\lambda/\gamma)},$$ a seemingly explicit formula whose usefulness is debatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been doing a lot of work computing both average wait times and statistics related to reliable wait times.

A class of infinite summation solutions techniques are really useful here.

A = 1 + 2*u + 3*u^2 + 4*u^3 ...

B = 1 + u + u^2 + u^3 ...
B = 1 / (1-u)

A - B = u + 2*u^2 + 3*u^3 ...

A - B = u * A

A - u *A = B

A = B/(1-u)  = 1/(1-u)^2

A-B = u/(1-u)^2

This should help out quite a bit.

For Queue Variance computations consider the following

d/du (A-B) = 1 + 4*u + 9*u^2 + 16*u^3...

d/du(A-B) = d/du (u/(1-u)^2) = (1+u)/(1-u)^3

Applying this to Queue and Markov Chains such as MM1 Queues:

Odds of being in line in position n.  Pn = (1-U)*U^n
U = Arrival_Rate/Execution_Rate.

How long on average does someone wait in line?

Time each person waits times probability of being in that position in line.

L = Arrival Rate (Units/time)
M = Execution Rate (Units/time)

Wait_Queue_Average = sum_n (n/M) * Pn  = sum_n (n/M)*(1-U)*U^n

Wait_Queue = 0 + 1/M*(1-U)*U + 2/M*(1-U)*U^2 + 3/M*(1-U)*U^3...

Wait_Queue = (1-U)/M * (U + 2*U^2 + 3*U^3...)

This looks a lot like our friend before...

Wait_Queue = (1-U)/M * (A-B) = (1-U)/M*(U/(1-U)^2) = U/(M*(1-U))
U=L/M  so 
Wait_Queue = L/M / (M * (1-L/M)) = L/M * 1/(M-L)  or the exact queue wait time for a MM1 Queue worked out from first principles of the odds of forming a line and waiting for processing at each step in the line.

Suppose I wanted to know the sigma in the wait time.

Variance = Sum Squared minus average squared.
Sigma = sqrt(Variance)

Sum Squared = sum_n (Wait_n * Wait_n * Probabilty_n)
Sum Squared = sum_n ((n/M) * (n/M) * (1-U)*U^n)

= 0 + (1/M^2)*(1-U)*U + 4/M^2*(1-U)*U^2 + 9/M^2*(1-U)*U^3 + 16/M^3*(1-U)*U^4...
= 1/M^2 * (1-U) * ( U + 4*U^2 + 9*U^3 + 16*U^4...)

#### which again looks like one of our friends.

I hope these help.